# Preventing XML file caching

Tags: xml, caching, meta-tags

I have a page that calls for information from an XML file, and when information appended to the XML its refreshes the page; but the new information doesn't automatically show up you need to refresh the page a few times for it to appear.

I've determined that this is a caching issue, since the new/appended information shows up immediately if I use any other browser to display the page as soon as the info is submitted.

My question is:
Is it possible to use  in an XML file so to prevent that XML file itself from being cached, and if so how?
If I can't do that and have to put it in the HTML file, is there any way to only specify the XML file thats being loaded or would I have to apply it to the entire page?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache" />`

`<stuff>`

`<someSpecificStuff/>`

`</stuff>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are transferring the XML over HTTP then you can use the HTTP headers to control caching. There is a good tutorial here http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

If you have access to the server that is serving the file you can start there. Different languages and servers implement caching controls in different ways. For example, .Net uses the [HttpCachePolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). [IIS also allows you to set headers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247404).

Java, PHP, Apache all have solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me not to load cached data.xml in the background.

NOTE: It does not work cross-domain.

```
<iframe id="dataXml" src="data.xml" width="1" height="1" style="border: 0px;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() {document.getElementById("dataXml").contentWindow.location.reload(true);}</script>
```